# How to use javascript for a simple game

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

I want to add few divs and after clicking on them they should disappear and score should increase by 1 using javascript.. what should I do

Comment: *What should I do"* ... study some tutorials, examples etc from web. Question as it stands is far too broad for SO as per guidelines in the [help]

Comment: write code, when stuck ask question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hello Subhrajeet,**

Thank you very much for your question. It is by asking that we all have learned, **however**, I encourage you to try at least to put some code together prior to ask something so that we can assist you fixing it if needed.

I put together and idea based in what you've asked. I certainly hope this help you with your inquiry. Happy coding and keep learning, this is an amazing adventure!

```js
function remove() {
  this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);
  let currScore = parseInt(document.getElementById("score").innerHTML)+1;
  if (currScore == 6) {
 document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = "You Won!!!";
} else {
  document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = currScore;
}

}

let list = document.querySelectorAll('div');
let button = document.querySelectorAll('span');

for (var i = 0, len = list.length; i < len; i++) {
  button[i].addEventListener('click', remove, false);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 class="text-info text-uppercase">Wacky Box Clicking Game</h1>
  <p>This game consists of clicking on the happy face to make it dissapear. When you've reached six, you are a WINNER! yeeey! ☺</p>
  <h3 class="text-muted">CURRENT SCORE: <b class="text-danger" id="score">0</b></h3>
<section class="row">
<div class="col-sm-2 boxie display-2 text-info"><span> ☺</span></div>
<div class="col-sm-2 boxie display-2 text-success"><span> ☺</span></div>
<div class="col-sm-2 boxie display-2 text-danger"><span> ☺</span></div>
<div class="col-sm-2 boxie display-2 text-warning"><span> ☺</span></div>
<div class="col-sm-2 boxie display-2 text-primary"><span> ☺</span></div>
<div class="col-sm-2 boxie display-2 text-info"><span> ☺</span></div>
<section>
</body>
</html>
```